# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом И? (2)

Tags: запятые

*В результате прекращения права собственности Брюханов ухудшил свои жилищные условия и он стал являться нуждающимся в жилых помещениях.*

Comment: А кто такой *он?*

Comment: Вероятно, сам Брюханов. Это такая оригинальная стилистика.

Answer (score 1):

***В результате прекращения права собственности** Брюханов ухудшил свои жилищные условия, и (как следствие этого) он стал являться нуждающимся в жилых помещениях.*

**Примечание.** Конечно, предложение выглядит неестественно, его следует написать так: *В результате прекращения права собственности Брюханов ухудшил свои жилищные условия и стал являться нуждающимся в жилых помещениях.*

Обстоятельственный оборот по семантике является общей причиной, но ССП построено таким образом, что можно увидеть причинно-следственную связь между двумя простыми предложениями; также там разные видовые формы глагола.

В таком случае они являются **неоднородными,**  обстоятельство относится только к первому предложению. Тогда **запятая ставится,** пауза в речи также присутствует.

Answer (score 0):

> В результате прекращения права собственности Брюханов ухудшил свои жилищные условия и он стал являться нуждающимся в жилых помещениях.

Если «ухудшил», то по своей воле? Значит, не «в результате прекращения», а своими руками: прекратив (передав/отказавшись от) право собственности и тем ухудшив (формально, стало быть) условия, смог получить статус (от «стал являться» веет мистикой) нуждающегося в жилье.

*Брюханов, отказавшись от права собственности и намеренно ухудшив условия проживания, сумел получить статус нуждающегося в жилье.*

Если Б. не прекращал и не ухушал, смысл фразы должен быть нейтральным.

*По прекращениии права собственности у Брюханова ухудшились условия проживания, и он стал нуждающимся в жилье.*